# Modelo relacional de una estructura organizativa, SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

haber si alguien puede ayudarme..

Estoy creando una base de datos para una estructura organizativa de una empresa que tiene diferentes niveles, es decir tengo un nodo principal del que cuelgan más hijos y así en 6 niveles. Es decir algo así..

[image]

La estructura organizativa vendría a ser algo como la parte izquierda de la imagen, y la parte derecha representa las tablas de como estoy intentando crear la estructura

Mi duda es si la forma correcta es crear diferentes tablas y juntarlas haciendo claves primarias y foraneas. Además cada tabla tiene los mismos atributos, código, nombre, y descripción, por lo que me sale la duda de si tendría que hacer una especialización, pero si hiciera una especialización los hijos heredan los atributos y luego los hijos se relacionarían? No se si se puede hacer que los hijos en una especialización dependan unos con otros, para representar los niveles de la estructura.

He decido empezar por crear el diagrama e-r y al estar colgando uno de otros, no están dependiendo del anterior? Es decir, no deberían ser entidades débiles? Pero si fueran entidades débiles, en el tercer nivel tendríamos una entidad débil de una entidad débil y creo que esto no puede hacerse.

No se si me he expresado bien, si alguien puede echarme una mano y darme una idea de como tendría que hacer la base de datos organizativa se lo agradecería.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te diría que las tablas sean una sola, con un referencia a ellas mismas. Luego un campo que sea el tipo DO, GC,VO, etc.. Esa columna puede ser perfectamente una clave foránea a otra tabla que se llame tipo pero es cosa tuya ya que no necesariamente deba ser así.

Quedaría algo como:

Nodo

id_nodo | nombre| codigo | id_nodo (si no es null indica es una hija) | tipo

-------------------------- la otra alternativa

Nodo

id_nodo | nombre| codigo | id_nodo | id_tipo

Tipo

id | nombre_tipo <- GC, VO, etc...

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has dado la clave para aclarar las dudas que tenía, solo veo un problema ahora, en cuanto a rendimiento, el tener todos los datos en una sola tabla, hará que las consultas sean más lentas no? O me estoy equivocando? Más que todo porque los 3 primeros niveles tendrían pocos datos pero el sexto nivel puede tener unas 1300 entradas.. de todas formas gracias por tu aporte hermano!

Comment: Bueno dependiendo como obtengas los datos, si vas a obtener absolutamente todo podrías ver una degradación pero no tiene sentido traer las 1300 filas hijas del nivel 5... en todo caso harías una paginación algo así. De igual manera si va a obtener las 1300 filas de UN SOLO NODO de nivel 5 tampoco es que la BD se vaya a explotar si la cantidad de usuarios es baja... De nuevo, todo depende de lo que quieras hacer ya que 1300 filas para la BD es un grano de arena en el desierto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia de responder enserio. No tengo pensado traer todos esos datos sin más, así que tiraré para adelante con la información que me has dado. Gracias!

Comment: De nada :D saludos!

Comment: Hola @zerocool, de casualidad sabes como funciona en el diagrama entidad relación, la especialización? No acabo de entender la cardinalidad. La cardinalidad del lado de la sueprentidad si la entiendo pero la de las subentidades no, no veo la diferencia entre una especialziación solapada y exclusiva en cuanto a cardinalidades, como debería representarlo para que no pueda tener por ejemplo que una persona  sea alumno y profesor a la vez o para que si lo sea. Y en el momento de pasarlo a tablas que  me restringe que no pueda tener en la tabla de alumnos y profesores la misma persona. Gracias!

Comment: A ver, lo primero es identificar si esa exclusividad es totalmente necesaria, de ser así podrías entonces crear dos tablas una de profesor y otra de alumnos pero parte de eso que sea estricto ya que un profesor podría ser alumno en algún momento no?

Comment: Fijate en https://ibb.co/b5Vmz7 en el caso A es como te planteo la respuesta, en el caso B tendrías que sacar el id de la misma tabla y crear una nueva (en el modelo fisico, el mer queda como en la imagen). Saludos!